# Show/Hide Expo Video Controller on press (Android Platform)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm using expo-av to create a video player. Everything works fine on iOS but in Android platform, I can't tap on the screen to manually show/hide the video controller. Any solution for this? Thank you guys.
Here is the code:

```
      <Video
        source={{
          uri: 'https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
        style={styles.videoPlayer}
        useNativeControls
        
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set **`useNativeControls`** to **`false`** to hide the video controls and you can also change it back to **`true`** to show the video controls again.

Code for example:

```js
import { TouchableOpacity, useState, useCallback } from "react-native";
import { Video } from "expo-av";

export default function VideoComponent() {
  const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(false);

  const toggleControls = useCallback(() => {
    setShowControls((showControls) => !showControls);
  }, []);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => toggleControls()}>
      <Video
        source={{
          uri: "https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
        }}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
        style={styles.videoPlayer}
        useNativeControls={showControls}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: If we use this way, it will rerender every time we click on the video..

Comment: @nmnhon that's why you can see that I've used `usecallback`. So it will not re-render. Just the value of `showControls` will be changed

Comment: Right but when I click on the video, it flickers a bit and it looks like a rerender

Comment: @nmnhon Maybe you are using `TouchableOpacity` from my code above. It is the effect of `TouchableOpacity` and it is not re-rendering. You can disable it by setting the attribute `activeOpacity`. You can use `activeOpacity={1}`. To make it easier I've updated the above code. Please check it.

Comment: ok it work perfectly now, tysm.